Parsing numbers with a comma decimal separator with FParsec
Is it possible to use FParsec's built-in parsers for numbers (e.g. pfloat, numberLiteral) with different culture settings and parse numbers with a comma as a decimal separator? And if not, what would be the alternative?

You need to know the culture in advance. There's no way even a human can tell what 123.456 or 123,456 means without knowing the culture

Ofc. but how can we let FParsec know which culture to use?

Check the source code. It uses Double.Parse and hard-codes CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. You'll have to adapt this code to use a CultureInfo passed as a parameter to pfloat
